# Non-dimensional flux

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum, drag, flow

My book states that when a flow around object is considered,

> Non dimensional momentum flux is defined as the drag coefficient

In case of flow through tubes it states

> The non dimensional momentum flux is defined as the friction factor

What do these statements mean? What do they practically define?

Comment: Related??  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy_friction_factor_formulae

Comment: Sorry but Not relevant to what I asked :(

Comment: It's a fluid mechanics technique for making the calculations easier https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-dimensionalization_and_scaling_of_the_Navier–Stokes_equations

Comment: They are just definitions. The form of the dimensionless quantities however are determined using Buckingham Pi theorem.